# Why am I getting a certificate error while searching google.com.ph?

Tags: firefox

I have searched many solutions but it didn't work on me please help.

(This is the message)
Your connection is not secure

The owner of `www.google.com.ph` has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.
(end of message)

(The certificate)

`https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=MRmhWOLNB-7O8gfmhKPoDQ&gws_rd=ssl` Peer’s Certificate issuer is not recognized. HTTP Strict Transport Security: false HTTP Public Key Pinning: true Certificate chain:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDHTCCAgWgAwIBAgIRAOaoGFboIEzBazRQq+owKjUwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
>   UzEpMCcGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYaaW5mb0B0ZWNobm9sb2dpZW1vdW5hYy5jb20xCzAJ
>   BgNVBAYTAkVOMRkwFwYDVQQDDBAyNjNmMGM5NWNjZDVlYmFiMB4XDTE3MDEyNTEw
>   MDgwMFoXDTE3MDQxOTEwMDgwMFowaTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgMCkNh
>   bGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcMDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxEzARBgNVBAoMCkdvb2ds
>   ZSBJbmMxGDAWBgNVBAMMDyouZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS5waDCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEF
>   AAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAxG2tDjKrM41STdy2LUEgW/YNlqDU3DgYOI6YJI9nzRFrFIoa
>   P6CMc0w5Y9KBRMPDjUqlXBHm7MS3YMJWxRUze5/VZ3qQQJF/tm8AFMim8DRjIkpc
>   /MkOhquYOUCt7eG4mDgS4307oaopoVU5XGIGyT6t5FoXyzDY1pRfH8BEBA0CAwEA
>   AaNaMFgwKQYDVR0RBCIwIIIPKi5nb29nbGUuY29tLnBogg1nb29nbGUuY29tLnBo
>   MAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMA0G
>   CSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQA05WDImY8XxmLDs2gplZXknOLZfH094iNxGUbPhNdI
>   7jwTxZziR6iSxf0EhGyxkr4x/Q9Mchnca3qIqLHAf5ieqb5/wrDYLQFd++OrYE00
>   EtovOUf7CVuy9gMQ26hzgdcZqbmNQivM97kZual/rzOKIwtdsoyifh3sy1DbXKaE
>   WQdgYQeAyIRFW8/goB6tM5b1/E6L78PjTiIlFqAygSPAi0mfL2LLyhxvzanLjWSJ
>   kwpbWQNBYhwaBrNiTka5tjgMqZwA0NJE9gU0sHBAbGPLvIC0+euZL9kZe4F/IF4L
>   QpJrXJi/NxEH5JWhykipg0U1jQDPVfWCJ+IILWFF/LBt
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> (end of certificate)

Note that I'm searching on `google.com.ph`

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the [Social2Search](http://technologiemounac.com/home) browser addon from your computer.

It appears to be intercepting connections to web sites you visit, probably to inject its content into web pages. In the process, it is inserting its own invalid SSL certificates into HTTP connections.

A human-readable version of the certificate is below -- the "issuer" of the certificate is what led me to Social2Search:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            e6:a8:18:56:e8:20:4c:c1:6b:34:50:ab:ea:30:2a:35
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: emailAddress=info@technologiemounac.com, C=EN, CN=263f0c95ccd5ebab
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan 25 10:08:00 2017 GMT
            Not After : Apr 19 10:08:00 2017 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc, CN=*.google.com.ph
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus (1024 bit):
                    00:c4:6d:ad:0e:32:ab:33:8d:52:4d:dc:b6:2d:41:
                    20:5b:f6:0d:96:a0:d4:dc:38:18:38:8e:98:24:8f:
                    67:cd:11:6b:14:8a:1a:3f:a0:8c:73:4c:39:63:d2:
                    81:44:c3:c3:8d:4a:a5:5c:11:e6:ec:c4:b7:60:c2:
                    56:c5:15:33:7b:9f:d5:67:7a:90:40:91:7f:b6:6f:
                    00:14:c8:a6:f0:34:63:22:4a:5c:fc:c9:0e:86:ab:
                    98:39:40:ad:ed:e1:b8:98:38:12:e3:7d:3b:a1:aa:
                    29:a1:55:39:5c:62:06:c9:3e:ad:e4:5a:17:cb:30:
                    d8:d6:94:5f:1f:c0:44:04:0d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:*.google.com.ph, DNS:google.com.ph
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        34:e5:60:c8:99:8f:17:c6:62:c3:b3:68:29:95:95:e4:9c:e2:
        d9:7c:7d:3d:e2:23:71:19:46:cf:84:d7:48:ee:3c:13:c5:9c:
        e2:47:a8:92:c5:fd:04:84:6c:b1:92:be:31:fd:0f:4c:72:19:
        dc:6b:7a:88:a8:b1:c0:7f:98:9e:a9:be:7f:c2:b0:d8:2d:01:
        5d:fb:e3:ab:60:4d:34:12:da:2f:39:47:fb:09:5b:b2:f6:03:
        10:db:a8:73:81:d7:19:a9:b9:8d:42:2b:cc:f7:b9:19:b9:a9:
        7f:af:33:8a:23:0b:5d:b2:8c:a2:7e:1d:ec:cb:50:db:5c:a6:
        84:59:07:60:61:07:80:c8:84:45:5b:cf:e0:a0:1e:ad:33:96:
        f5:fc:4e:8b:ef:c3:e3:4e:22:25:16:a0:32:81:23:c0:8b:49:
        9f:2f:62:cb:ca:1c:6f:cd:a9:cb:8d:64:89:93:0a:5b:59:03:
        41:62:1c:1a:06:b3:62:4e:46:b9:b6:38:0c:a9:9c:00:d0:d2:
        44:f6:05:34:b0:70:40:6c:63:cb:bc:80:b4:f9:eb:99:2f:d9:
        19:7b:81:7f:20:5e:0b:42:92:6b:5c:98:bf:37:11:07:e4:95:
        a1:ca:48:a9:83:45:35:8d:00:cf:55:f5:82:27:e2:08:2d:61:
        45:fc:b0:6d
```